# High side MOSFET gate driver for pure DC application (non PWM)

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, mosfet-driver

I want to drive a highside MOSFET which is supposed to be on for hours.

I tried TI's approach of using a 555 timer and IR2110 but from my simulation on LTspice, the outputs at the  HO pin of the IR2110 and source of the mosfet are still oscillating. [This is the app note I am using.](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva444/slva444.pdf)

Please help me figure out the problem with my circuit.

[image]

HO pin output:

[image]

Source voltage:

[image]

Is there something wrong with my circuit? If I were to use an alternative method, can I use a 96V power supply at the gate seeing that the specs are +/-20V for the IPP11N15N3?

Comment: Be careful. 20 V is max rating but will degrade the gate oxide layer over time. Don’t use it continuously.

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t switch Hi-side MOSFET, the charge pump cannot charge VB, as D3 cannot be polarized because VS is much higher voltage than C5. If you apply some pulse off to this MOSFET, then VS will be grounded through R5 and charge pump can work.
If you cannot switch off the high side, then a floating power supply is needed for VS - VB.

Also look to IR2110 datasheet, VB min. should be 10 V, in your circuit is lower than 6 V. This could be an issue. Rise power supply of 555 and check.
[image]